# How do I use Regex in python to remove ALL characters EXCEPT letters

Tags: python, regex, string

I have text file like this:

```
...yolo wut is up dud! es.... heyo
eggssss hello...33421?
```

---

I tried doing this:

```
re.sub("[^a-zA-Z] ", "", string)
```

but it doesn't work, it leaves in numbers
I want it to create the two lined text file into a string with spaces in between like this:

```
yolo wut is up dud es heyo eggssss hello
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To end up with a one line string, you can do this as a 2-stage process:

1. remove all non-letter and whitespace characters
2. replace sequences of whitespace characters with a single space

For example:

```
string = '''...yolo wut is up dud! es.... heyo
eggssss hello...33421?'''
print(re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]', '', string)))
```

Output:

```
yolo wut is up dud es heyo eggssss hello
```

Answer (score 0):

The space in the quotes could be making it not match some parts.

Try using
    re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", string)

Comment: doesn't change anything

Comment: Did you try putting the space inside the brackets? (“[^a-zA-Z ]”).   
「Intended line feed stripped by site」    
re.sub("[^a-zA-Z ]", "", string) (might mess up with the newline)  
「Intended line feed stripped by site」    
or  
「Intended line feed stripped by site」    
re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", string) (might add many extra spaces)

Comment: @JohnSmith13345 I think you might have forgotten the extra whitespace in your code.

Answer (score 0):

as \w matches every letter, using it in uppercase "\W" may have the effect that you want

```
>>> re.sub("\\W", "", "...yolo wut is up dud! es.... heyo")
```

'yolowutisupdudesheyo'

**Edit**

To keep the spaces, your code is almost right, you just have to fix the space position inside the first argument on re.sub... like this

```
>>> re.sub("[^a-zA-Z ]", "", string)
```

'yolo wut is up dud es heyo'